# My lightbox stopped working with no code change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, lightbox

I used fancboxy to include an iframe for PDF viewing for a resume, and all of a sudden, the scripting agent will not work.

The code never changed, but I did clean some of the header CSS to incorporate a universal CSS file to span my entire project.  I reverted back to the old CSS filed and even downloaded a fresh copy of the old fancybox files ( kept the fancybox files as a subdirectory to my html in /fancybox/, but the site still acts as it would without the script.  (...) indicate code like charsets, viewports, , unrelated code to the issue, etc...  My necessary code is:

inside the head:

```
<head>
      ...
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href ="css/styles.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href ="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css"/>
      ...
    </head>
```

Inside the body:

```
   <div class ="resume">
       <div class = "resume-head">
      <h2>Resume</h2>
      </div>
   <div class="main">
   <div class="breaker-resume"><!-- //--></div>
    <a href="httpdocs/bin/resume.pdf" download class="download_resume" title="Download">download PDF</a>
    <a href="httpdocs/bin/resume.jpg" download class="download_resume" title="Download">download JPG</a>  
    <a href="assets/resume.pdf" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" title="My Resume"><img src="assets/resume.jpg"/></a><br>

</div>
</div>

   <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.fancybox').fancybox();
        });
    </script>
```

Everything else is just a nav bar and a footer.  I call my js here, right before the closing body tag:

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>


 </body>
```

Anyway, it seems as if the script never runs, the jpg is clicked at:

```
<a href="assets/resume.pdf" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" title="Harris's Resume"><img src="assets/resume.jpg"/></a><br>
```

and the PDF opens on the next page.  Any idea where I might be going wrong>

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running `$(document).ready(...);` after loading the js files at the end of your page?

Comment: try to put fancybox script below jquery.fancybox.pack.js and see if it makes the difference

Comment: Maybe browser update, breaking compatibility ?

Comment: what is the error in console

Comment: Ahh man, thanks!  Such a blatant oversight too - When I readjusted the js calls, I moved them from the head to the body and left the inline script where it was, thus ignoring it altogether - thanks!